# What is a common approach to memoize or not React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memoization

Let's say i have a component like this

```
const AngelsList = ({ angels, ...otherProps }) => 
  <div className='AngelsListBlock'>
    <div className='AngelsList'>
      { angels.map(angel => <Angel item={angel} />) }
    </div>

    // some other elements with otherProps
  </div>
```

and let's say angels array has 200 items. Is there are any sence to memoize this part

```
<div className='AngelsList'>
  { angels.map(angel => <Angel item={angel} />) }
</div>
```

considering that each Angel component has many dom elements inside it, but has no expensive calculations?

If i'll memoize that block with 200 angels inside will it tell React to leave DOM element `<div className='AngelsList'>` as it is and not check the properties of all its children or memoization will influence only JSX object and checking DOM properties will happen anyway?

Hopefully i explained clearly

Comment: Do the user view all the `200 angels` at once? All the DOM elements are above the viewport? If not, then you could use something like `https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window` to only render component which are above the viewport.

Comment: @PrateekThapa The question is not about it

Answer (score 0):

First of all - let's clearly define what `memoization` means.
From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization):

> In computing, memoization or memoisation is an optimization technique used primarily to speed up computer programs by storing the results of expensive function calls and returning the cached result when the same inputs occur again.

So, the memoization is storing of results of function calls. In the scope of `react` - you gonna store the result of the `render` function (if that's class component), or the result of calling Functional Components (which function itself). 
**Therefore, any internal checks, DOM checks, internal calculations would be performed anyway during the initial function call and stored.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `useMemo` and split more component smaller to avoid rerender unnecessarily